# Change to next SNANPSHOT version in all modules of multi-module project

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module projects where the modules have all different non-SNAPSHOT versions. I want to change them all to the next SNAPSHOT version. With versions:set I need to explicitly set a new version, I would like to change all modules to [Current-Version+0.1]-SNAPSHOT. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with the `use-next-snapshots` goal of the `Versions Maven Plugin`

http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-next-snapshots-mojo.html

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. I need to change the versions of the projects, not of the dependencies.